# how to write .onclick method in jquery for all checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I have checkbox in my project which coming from database dynamically. Here i put only one but it could be many depends upon database table entry
    
       "                name="category" class="category">

I want to fire onclick event using jQuery when user click any of the checkbox. i Try but it is only fire when i click on first checkbox.
here is code which i try..

```
$("[type=checkbox]").click(function () {

                var category_array = new Array();
                var size_array = new Array();
                var color_array = new Array();
                $.each($("input[name='category']:checked"), function() {
                  category_array.push($(this).val());

                });
});
```

can anyone have idea why it is not working 
?? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you need to make sure the input name category is also an array. Change to category[]

Answer (score 1):

Its better to use the change event

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
  if(this.checked) {
    var category_array = new Array();
    var size_array = new Array();
    var color_array = new Array();
    $.each($("input[name='category']:checked"), function() {
        category_array.push($(this).val());
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**The selector for all checkboxes is:**

```
$('input[type=checkbox]')
```

Now do whatever you want with it!

**For dynamic checkboxes...**

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function(e) {
    //DO YOUR THANG
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this will solve you problem first change your html to this :

```
<div class="checkbox">
<label class="lbl-cat"><input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" name="category[]" class="category"> <?php echo $row["name"]; ?></label>

                                </div>
```

note that  its is `name="category[]"` not `name="category"`

and finally change your js for the same

```
$.each($("input[name='category[]']:checked"), function() {
                  category_array.push($(this).val());

                });
```